# Setting pandas conditions for columns by row, Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

(I suck at titling these questions...)

So I've gotten 90% of the way through a very laborious learning process with pandas, but I have one thing left to figure out.  Let me show an example (actual original is a comma-delimited CSV that has many more rows):

```
 Name    Price    Rating    URL                Notes1       Notes2            Notes3
 Foo     $450     9         a.com/x            NaN          NaN               NaN
 Bar     $99      5         see over           www.b.com    Hilarious         Nifty
 John    $551     2         www.c.com          Pretty       NaN               NaN
 Jane    $999     8         See Over in Notes  Funky        http://www.d.com  Groovy
```

The URL column can say many different things, but they all include "see over," and do not indicate with consistency which column to the right includes the site.

I would like to do a few things, here: first, move websites from any Notes column to URL; second, collapse all notes columns to one column with a new line between them.  So this (NaN's removed because pandas makes me in order to use them in df.loc):

```
 Name    Price    Rating    URL                Notes1       
 Foo     $450     9         a.com/x            
 Bar     $99      5         www.b.com          Hilarious
                                               Nifty
 John    $551     2         www.c.com          Pretty
 Jane    $999     8         http://www.d.com   Funky
                                               Groovy
```

I got partway there by doing this:

```
 df['URL'] = df['URL'].fillna('')
 df['Notes1'] = df['Notes1'].fillna('')
 df['Notes2'] = df['Notes2'].fillna('')
 df['Notes3'] = df['Notes3'].fillna('')
 to_move = df['URL'].str.lower().str.contains('see over')
 df.loc[to_move, 'URL'] = df['Notes1']
```

What I don't know is how to find the Notes column with either www or .com.  If I, for example, try to use my above method as a condition, e.g.:

```
 if df['Notes1'].str.lower().str.contains('www'):
    df.loc[to_move, 'URL'] = df['Notes1']
```

I get back `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`  But adding `.any()` or `.all()` has the obvious flaw that they don't give me what I'm looking for: with any, e.g., every line that meets the to_move requirement in URL will get whatever's in Notes1.  I need the check to occur row by row. For similar reasons, I can't even get started collapsing the Notes columns (and I don't know how to check for non-null empty string cells, either, a problem I created at this point).

Where it stands, I know I also have to move in Notes2 to Notes1, Notes3 to Notes2, and '' to Notes3 when the first condition is satisfied, because I don't want the leftover URLs in the Notes columns.  I'm sure pandas has easier routes than what I'm doing, because it's pandas, and when I try to do anything with pandas, I find out that it can be done in one line instead of my 20...

(PS, I don't care if the empty columns Notes2 and Notes3 are left over, b/c I'm not using them in my CSV import in the next step, though I can always learn more than I need)

UPDATE:  So I figured out a crummy verbose solution using my non-pandas python logic one step at a time.  I came up with this (same first five lines above, minus the df.loc line):

```
url_in1 = df['Notes1'].str.contains('\.com')
url_in2 = df['Notes2'].str.contains('\.com')
to_move = df['URL'].str.lower().str.contains('see-over')
to_move1 = to_move & url_in1 
to_move2 = to_move & url_in2
df.loc[to_move1, 'URL'] = df.loc[url_in1, 'Notes1']
df.loc[url_in1, 'Notes1'] = df['Notes2']
df.loc[url_in1, 'Notes2'] = ''
df.loc[to_move2, 'URL'] = df.loc[url_in2, 'Notes2']
df.loc[url_in2, 'Notes2'] = ''
```

(Lines moved around and to_move repeated in actual code) I know there has to be a more efficient method...  This also doesn't collapse in the Notes columns, but that should be easy using the same method, except that I still don't know a good way to find the empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still learning pandas, so some parts of this code may be not so elegant, but general idea is - get all notes columns, find all urls in there, combine it with `URL` column and then concat remaining notes into `Notes1` column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas.core.strings as strings

# Just to get first notnull occurence
def geturl(s):
    try:
        return next(e for e in s if not pd.isnull(e))
    except:
        return np.NaN

df =  pd.read_csv("d:/temp/data2.txt")

dfnotes = df[[e for e in df.columns if 'Notes' in e]]

#       Notes1            Notes2  Notes3
# 0        NaN               NaN     NaN
# 1  www.b.com         Hilarious   Nifty
# 2     Pretty               NaN     NaN
# 3      Funky  http://www.d.com  Groovy

dfurls = dfnotes.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\.com'), axis=1)
dfurls = dfurls.fillna(False).astype(bool)

#   Notes1 Notes2 Notes3
# 0  False  False  False
# 1   True  False  False
# 2  False  False  False
# 3  False   True  False

turl = dfnotes[dfurls].apply(geturl, axis=1)

df['URL'] = np.where(turl.isnull(), df['URL'], turl)
df['Notes1'] = dfnotes[~dfurls].apply(lambda x: strings.str_cat(x[~x.isnull()], sep=' '), axis=1)

del df['Notes2']
del df['Notes3']

df
#    Name Price  Rating               URL           Notes1
# 0   Foo  $450       9           a.com/x                 
# 1   Bar   $99       5         www.b.com  Hilarious Nifty
# 2  John  $551       2         www.c.com           Pretty
# 3  Jane  $999       8  http://www.d.com     Funky Groovy
```